# "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: userName" error when installing MSSQL 2014 Express in Docker

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, docker, dockerfile

When I try installing MSSQL 2014 Express in Dockerfile, it fails with error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: userName".

```
The following error occurred:
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: userName

Error result: -2147467261
Result facility code: 0
Result error code: 16387

Please review the summary.txt log for further details
Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2014 12.00.5000.00
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; cd extracted; ./setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /FEATURES=SQLEngine /UPDATEENABLED=0 /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS" /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=0 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This is how my Dockerfile looks like (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
COPY SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe ./
RUN .\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /x:extracted /u
RUN cd extracted; ./setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /FEATURES=SQLEngine /UPDATEENABLED=0 /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS" /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=0 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

The strange thing is, when I replace the last RUN command with `ENTRYPOINT powershell`, start the container and then run the exact same command, it works and the error isn't thrown.

The only thing I suspect to be a problem is that docker runs commands as "no user". But...

This is a result of whoami command in running container:
`user manager\containeradministrator`

I have tried putting `RUN whoami` to Dockerfile to confirm my hypothesis but the output is the same.

I have no idea what else to do, so thanks for any suggestions :).

Comment: The error means that a stored procedure was called with a NULL parameter. The parameter name suggest you forgot a user name somewher.

Comment: Instead of *installing* SQL Server Express inside the container, why don't you use the [official SQL Server Express image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express/)? Otherwise you'll have to reinstall the database each time you start the container, unless you commit the changes.

Comment: We need it for testing and the official image is for 2016 version. We'd like to verify that 2014 works as well. I don't know where to specify user parameter since the same command works when I am running it inside a started container.

Comment: You can use a compatibility level to make a database compatible with a specific version. Better than using a product that isn't *officially* supported to work in a container. "Officially" means that you don't have to worry about incompatibilities and bugs when working inside a container. It also means as soon as such problems are discovered, they will be fixed by Microsoft and the container image will be updated

Comment: I disagree, our company states that our product will work on 2014 database, not on 2016 in compatibility mode. True, most of the time it may be the same thing but not necessarily, Microsoft can have their own bugs as well. We need to test it against what we claim to support. In the past, "official" image was 2014 and I have based my image on this previous "official" version. So I believe 2014 is able to run in container.

Comment: You probably misunderstood what I wrote. You are testing, not developing. You don't want to test the database's potential problems along with your own products. In any case, if you want to create a 2014 container, create a 2014 container, not a container that installs 2014. That means, create the container, install 2014 then commit the changes and reuse it.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed possible but to create image automatically from Dockerfile rather than from manually configured container is best practice since it is automatically reproducible and any other developer can see "what the image is made of". At least in my company I am expected to do it this way. My question is simply about why is it possible to do it manually and impossible via Dockerfile when all commands are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've finally found what causes the problem. The error occurs when using powershell as default shell (`SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]`)

I made it work by skipping SHELL command and running installations from default command line.

```
RUN /SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /qs /x:setup
RUN /setup/setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /FEATURES=SQLEngine /UPDATEENABLED=0 /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS" /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=0 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

MSSQL 2008, 2012 and 2016 all work ok with powershell, only 2014 has this issue.

Comment: Also, to be noted that the we need to use double quotes when using the default command prompt command, instead of the single quotes when using the powershell command.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft used to maintain SQL Server 2014 images. You can find them in Git history here: https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/cc2402f91e37ce9ad7e108f3f51bbfe99f201e0b/samples/manage/windows-containers/mssql-server-2014-express-windows

```
ENV sql_express_download_url "https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/5/6/156992E6-F7C7-4E55-833D-249BD2348138/ENU/x64/SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"
ENV sa_password _
ENV attach_dbs "[]"

# make install files accessible
COPY . /
WORKDIR /

# download and install Microsoft SQL 2014 Express Edition in one step
RUN powershell -Command (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%sql_express_download_url%', 'sqlexpress.exe') && /sqlexpress.exe /qs /x:setup && /setup/setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /FEATURES=SQLEngine /UPDATEENABLED=0 /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS" /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=0 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS && del /F /Q sqlexpress.exe && rd /q /s setup

RUN powershell -Command \
        set-strictmode -version latest ; \
        stop-service MSSQL`$SQLEXPRESS ; \
        set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\mssql12.SQLEXPRESS\mssqlserver\supersocketnetlib\tcp\ipall' -name tcpdynamicports -value '' ; \
        set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\mssql12.SQLEXPRESS\mssqlserver\supersocketnetlib\tcp\ipall' -name tcpport -value 1433 ; \
        set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\mssql12.SQLEXPRESS\mssqlserver\' -name LoginMode -value 2 ;

CMD powershell ./start -sa_password %sa_password% -attach_dbs \"%attach_dbs%\" -Verbose
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same error message. 
My problem was to use following parameter:
/SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUHTORITY\Network Service"

When I have disgared this parameter, installation worked.

Answer (score 0):

Been struggling with this issue on a SQL 2016 installation (via Powershell) and eventually traced the problem to something different than listed here.
My SQL installation via a batch script had "/ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=False" but via powershell it required "/ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=True".